# Write to a file from a for loop

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write data from a for loop to a text file, I know that the F.write(string) only takes strings and not tags.

I assume I need to open the file before the for loop starts, but I am a bit lost after that. I thought I could use the tag instead of a string by opening the file before the for loop starts. Any suggestions?

```
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://blablalballa.com')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
target = soup.find_all("span", class_=none)
F = open("data.txt", "w")

for data in target:
print(data.string)

F.write(data.string)
F.write("\n")
F.close()
```

F.write(data.string)

"TypeError: write() argument bust be str, not None"

Comment: `target` is not defined, and the loop isn't properly indented

Comment: Is the indentation in your example code correct? As it is right now, the for loop is empty because the contents are not indented.

Comment: @Rob The for loop isn't empty, it's a syntax error: `IndentationError: expected an indented block` at line 7

Comment: Please update your question with the error you are seeing.

Comment: Updated, the loop is working fine without the write to file code. But as soon as I try to write the text from the loop into .txt it complains, it does not like F.write(data.string).

Comment: You need to move the `F.write()` calls inside the `for` loop, i.e. indent them to the same level as the `print()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess one problem might be `none`, instead of which, we would use `class_=''`. Another problem might be the `data.string` is None. You can likely use `str()` or write an if statement for that.

```
import urllib, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://google.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
target = soup.find_all("span", class_='')
F = open("data.txt", "w")

output = ''
for data in target:
    output += str(data)

F.write(str(output))
F.write("\n")
F.close()
```

#### Output

```
> <span id="gbe"></span><span id="footer"><div
> style="font-size:10pt"><div id="fll" style="margin:19px
> auto;text-align:center"><a
> href="/intl/en/ads/">Advertising Programs</a><a
> href="/services/">Business Solutions</a><a
> href="/intl/en/about.html">About Google</a></div></div><p
> style="color:#767676;font-size:8pt">© 2019 - <a
> href="/intl/en/policies/privacy/">Privacy</a> - <a
> href="/intl/en/policies/terms/">Terms</a></p></span>
```

Comment: May I ask you, since we put data.string into a variable called output. My \n does not work properly. Example: My page Logout CarScootersBikes. The specific text I'm interested in is in the part which do not get a new row. Weird?